# Easy way to parse array values

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

Is there util that parses array content without the need of iterating it and parsing each value?

input: `['2','3','7']`

output: `[2, 3, 7]`

Comment: What?  You mean turn string into integer or what?

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes, that's right

Comment: can we read a text without iterating by all letters? i don't think so. to do operations on array values there's always the need to iterating it. if you uses an function, this function will for sure itinerate through its values

Comment: @leo_ap Indeed. Wrong expression, pardon me

Comment: Why is this necessary? For most purposes where an int is needed, PHP will automatically handle the conversion anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This obviously iterates internally, but you don't have to code an iterator:

```
$output = array_map('intval', $input);
```

Maps every value in `$input` to the `intval()` function and returns the result.  For things that cannot be converted into an integer you'll get `0` or for objects, a notice and that value will not be returned.

I can't tell if you want to remove `0` values or not from your comment, but if so:

```
$output = array_filter(array_map('intval', $input));
```

Comment: Can I hook to that fail convention `0`  case? I might have valid zeros in the input

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Do you mean remove `0` values???

Comment: ok my bad, understood

Comment: Yes, `['0','moo', '5', '7']` will end in `[0,0,5,7]` , right?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: @JockyDoe [See the PHP manual for the rules on string conversion to number](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion). Keep in mind that strings with mixed letters/numbers will convert to nonzero numbers if they begin with nonzero numbers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-map.php)

```
array = ["2","3","4"];

$intArray = array_map('intval', $array);
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the other answer, but with no explanation.

Comment: @Jocky Doe :).  It is always a benefit, to learn how functions work. So i added a link to the PHP Manual.